# Should I have aside element ouside or inside of main element?

Tags: html, seo, accessibility, semantic-markup

Let's say `aside` element includes "Oh, by the way …" content such as reading suggestions, advertisements, or cross sells.

1. Is it semantically okay to have `aside` outside of `main`?
2. If yes, does it have any advantage over accessibility if I keep `aside` outside of `main`, such as "skip to main content" command?
3. Last but not the least, I would like to know if there is any SEO impact if I include `aside` tag outside or inside of `main`.

Comment: Please note that asking for "SEO impact" is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Such questions can be asked on [webmasters.se].

Comment: Thanks @unor! I will keep this in my mind for future questions.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[In HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-aside-element) it’s only defined that `aside` is "related to the content around the `aside` element".

[In HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-aside-element) (CR) the definition [became more specific](https://github.com/travisleithead/html/commit/b55587163363da0822e6a76e4b9cf1c8f80b3d8d), as it now says that `aside` is "related to the content of the parenting *sectioning content*".

Following the newer definition, the `aside` element should be inside of the section element to which it is related. The `main` element is *not* a sectioning element (elements like `article`, `section`, `body`, `figure` etc. are). You can of course still place `aside` in `main`, but it will be related to the nearest sectioning element parent of `main`.

That means there is no semantic difference (for `aside`) in these two examples:

```html
<body>
  <main></main>
  <aside><!-- related to the body --></aside>
</body>
```

```html
<body>
  <main><aside><!-- related to the body --></aside></main>
</body>
```

Example that shows a few different cases:

```html
<body>

  <main>

    <article>

      <aside><!-- related to the article --></aside>

      <section>

        <aside><!-- related to the section --></aside>

        <blockquote>
          <aside><!-- related to the blockquote (not to the section!) --></aside>
        </blockquote>

        <div>
          <aside><!-- related to the section (not to the div!) --></aside>
        </div>

      </section>

    </article>

    <aside><!-- related to the body (not to the main!) --></aside>

  </main>

  <aside>
    <!-- related to the body -->
    <aside><!-- related to the (parent) aside --></aside>
  </aside>

  <nav>
    <aside><!-- related to the nav --></aside>
  </nav>

  <footer>
    <aside><!-- related to the body (not to the footer!) --></aside>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding more details. After referring to specs, I have marked yours as answer given that it is more relevant.

Comment: [WCAG success criterion 1.3.1: Info and Relationships](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/info-and-relationships.html)  identifies `aside` and `main` as landmarks. As such, they should not be nested. Nesting landmarks makes it difficult for people using assistive technologies to perceive such content.

Comment: @ZGuard: Did you maybe link to the wrong page? Couldn’t spot the relevant info on this page, but found it on https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/landmarks/complementary.html ("`complementary` landmarks should be top level landmarks"). As it can be semantically appropriate to nest `aside` inside `main`, maybe it would make sense to overwrite the `aside`’s implicit role by explicitly specifying a non-landmark one?

Comment: I realize the link I posted is very general. Your resource is more to the point. [An article from Deque University](https://dequeuniversity.com/assets/html/jquery-summit/html5/slides/landmarks.html) specifically mentions `aside`, suggesting it is interpreted as a `complementary` landmark. But overriding the semantics is a smart idea, especially if restructuring the HTML is off the table.

Comment: Further to @unor comment: "Landmark roles can be nested to identify parent/child relationships of the information being presented." https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/landmarks/index.html

Answer (score 14):

If your `<aside>` is directly related to the content in you `<main>` then I would leave it in the `<main>`. Now, that being said...

1. Yes, it is semantically ok to have `<aside>` outside a `<main>` (as in, it is valid, but your content might warrant otherwise).
2. I do not understand how you are thinking the skip link comes into play here, but otherwise `<aside>` outside a `<main>` has no harm nor benefit for accessibility. As long as you follow good structure and valid mark-up, you should be fine.
3. I am aware of none. I have `<aside>`s outside `<main>` on my site, and had `<aside>`s inside `<main>` as well, and I have seen no difference in my ranking. Given that search engines are generally opaque about specific bits like this, I would consider some A/B testing if you are concerned.

Related materials from HTML5 Doctor, which is written by one of the HTML5 spec editors:

- http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/
- http://html5doctor.com/tag/aside/
- http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/